# PHP CLI is not defining STDIN / STDOUT

Tags: php, cron, stdout, stdin

I have a cron set up up to run a PHP like so:

`*/10   *   *   *   *   env php -q /some/where/sessionGc.php`

Running the script from bash (`$ env php -q /some/where/sessionGc.php`) works great.

Running the script via the cron fails because the script checks for

`if( defined('STDIN') && defined('STDOUT') ) { ... }`

and those aren't defined.

All the PHP documentation I've found says those two variables should be defined automatically by PHP when being run CLI (including comments in the php.ini file).

Any idea what's going wrong here?

PHP v7.0.28, CentOS, Server API: CGI/FastCGI

Thanks for any help/clues you can provide!

Comment: I assume you are running the CLI and not the FastCGI exe

Comment: *"I have a cron set up"* - in what file did you write that line?

Comment: You better use the full path of the PHP interpreter you want to use. The cron jobs run within an environment that is very different than your usual terminal environment.

Comment: Thank you @RiggsFolly and @axiac ! That was the issue. After changing to the CLI path (`/usr/local/bin/php`) that fixed everything.

Comment: (If one of you want to reply as an answer I'll accept it.)